# How to update the timstamp while choosing the same item in drop-down list in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a script where it is able to print the current timestamp in Cell `C8` when I choose `Transfer` in cell `B8`. However, when I click `Transfer` in the drop-down list for the second time, the timestamp will not update since the word is still the same. My code is is attached below:

```
function onEdit(e){
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart >= 8) {
    if (e.value == 'Transfer') {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that cell `B8` need to change so that `OnEdit` function will change and print the current timestamp. I also know that I can include `Transfer 1`, `Transfer 2` in my drop-down list and my script but this is not an ideal way. Is there any way to change the timestamp even though I'm still choosing `Transfer` in the drop-down list? Possible other type of function instead of `OnEdit`?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your question, for example, when `const onSelectionChange = e => onEdit(e);` is put to the script editor and you tested your situation, is that the result you expect? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: Hi Ref, may I know which line of code for me to insert `const onSelectionChange = e => onEdit(e);` ? Sorry, I'm very new to google apps script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a clear of B8 before the `}else{` in the script?

i.e., after:

`e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(dt);`

... add this line (indented to the same level as the above line for clarity)...

`e.range.clearContent();`

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your solution. It is a great idea to clear the content in cell `B8`. However, the entire column C will be hidden to the users, so if I cleared cell `B8`, the Users might not know whether they had transferred their data.

Comment: or is it possible to set a time such that it will only clear the content after 10 seconds?

Comment: Keep in mind that we don't know your application or end goal at all, so it's hard to suggest what would make the most sense. I encourage you to look into how to work with setTimeout. This may solve your issue. As this site is not designed to be a free full-scale code-writing service, I'll leave it to you to explore that. Hopefully, that gets you closer to goal.

Comment: You really just need to set up an empty function below your onEdit function (call it, say, "wait") and then call that empty function from within setTimeout with a time of 10000 (ms), on the line above e.range.clearContent(). (With that, though I'm not typing it out exactly, you should be able to do it.)